# setup doesn't uninstall files

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I have a very simple setup project:

```
  <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" Name="$(var.ProductLongName)" Language="1033"
         Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <!-- Installation Parts -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="WindowsFolder">
        <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="b3250107-4859-4d5f-857c-1756af65ec32">
          <File Id='SomeFile' Name='SomeFile.scr'
                Source='SomeFile.scr' Vital='yes' />
           <!-- Other files -->
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductShortName)" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
      <!-- Note: The following ComponentGroupRef is required to pull in generated authoring from project references. -->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
    </Feature>

    <!-- Prerequisites -->
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT"/>

    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT]]>
    </Condition>

  </Product>
```

It installs ok and uninstall seem to finish ok too, but all files remain. They are not deleted.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to run uninstall with verbose logging? Start `msiexec /x {PRODUCT_GUID} /lv* uninstall.log`. It can give you a hint why msi decides not to remove this file.

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov, There are too much messages there. What I should look for?

Comment: You can always email it to me chrpai@deploymentengineering.com and I'll look through it.

Comment: @user626528 You should look for either file id `SomeFile` or its name `SomeFile.scr`. Any way you seem to have resolved your issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, this problem is gone when I changed component guid to a freshly generated. Don't really understand why. Weird.

Comment: Wow, this stupid bug cost me many, many hours. Thank god I finally found an answer. Thank you, oh kind anonymous user.

Comment: Oh, I changed my GUID in Product tag. As @StephenConnolly mentioned below, GUID should all be in upper case.

Comment: I had this for the second time now (within an month or so). Does anybody know ho wto avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

The component GUID in the OP was all in lower case. By convention MSI prefers GUIDs to be all in upper case just in case you need to pass the GUID across the service boundary as a (public) property. Was your new GUID all in upper case, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it's all uppercase. And I put it with braces {}. This can be an explanation.

Comment: WiX automatically adds {}'s and caps the guids during the build process.

Comment: So, the reason of this bug must be somewhere else.